# Lenovo ideapad S145 with Radeon Vega 10 - Backlight not working on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: lenovo, brightness, backlight

The laptop has an onboard GPU Radeon Vega 10. But the screen backlight is not working. I tried change the boot parameters like

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor
```

and tried to install `xbacklight`, but neither of them worked. There is a file in the `/sys/class/backlight` directory named "ideapad". The value of `cat /sys/class/backlight/ideapad/actual_brightness` is changing, but the brightness doesn't actually change.